# Active record design pattern[PHP/MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I refer to the code posted here:

http://codeslayer2010.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/developer-journal-2012-03-30-building-a-php-database-connection-class-from-scratch-singleton-activerecord/

This is all well and good for tables that have a single primary key. But what about tables that have two primary keys such as a composite table? How will the design pattern in the above link account for that? For as you can see, the load function in table.class.php only takes in a single id.

The only thing I can think of for a class representing a composite table is to extend the table class and override the load function, replacing it with one that takes in two ids. But however this seems messy and I was wondering if there was a neater way to accommodate the occurrence of composite tables.

Your thoughts on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't mean "two primary keys", you mean "a primary key that includes two columns". Use an array to store a primary key, with each column represented by an element in this array. Yii Framework works that way, you might find [their implementation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/db/schema/CDbCommandBuilder.php#L509) useful (although it could be too complex to start from).

Comment: I had a look at the Yii Framework implementation and in the comment for the createPkCriteria function it says "Use array for multiple primary keys." Is this a mistake? From what I understand based on what you said and my research into the matter, a table can only have one primary key.

Comment: I would interpret that comment as "use array for multiple values in the primary key".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to extend the structure of the table to have another column, which is the primary key. And set your current two columns to a combined unique key, so you can still be sure that the data is unique, but call it with one single value as primary key.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this Tobias?

Comment: You don't have to extend the PHP Code, because you can use one single primary key value and your data is still unique over these two columns where you're primary key is currently set on.